# connecting 3 PC (ubuntu) with static IP locally

Tags: networking, ubuntu, router, switch

sorry for the newbish question, I'm still not 100% in my routing understanding...

So I have 3 ubuntu PC:s connected by a switch, all of them with static ip set in `/etc/network/interface`.
The setup is

```
PC1: IP 192.168.0.117 subnetmask: 255.255.0.0
PC2: IP 192.168.1.220 subnetmask: 255.255.0.0
PC3: IP 192.168.0.125 subnetmask: 255.255.0.0
```

I can ping and connect between PC1 and PC3 but not between PC2 and PC1. I'm a bit confused since I thought the last two bytes being 0 in 255.255.0.0 subnetmask would make the all those 3 PC:s in the same subnetwork?

I can make this work by just changing PC2:s IP to 192.168.0.220, but this conflicts with other setups I have.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure your question is worded correctly? I ask because you don't mention PC3. Technically, your subnet mask of 255.255.0.0 does include 192.168.0.x and 192.168.1.x. It is also a gigantic subnet and 255.255.254.0 also includes both of those subnets without being so huge. That doesn't solve your problem though, as the communication should work with either mask. You say you can ping PC1 to PC2, but not PC2 to PC1. Is PC1 possibly running a firewall that is blocking ping? Can you ping PC1 from PC3 and vice versa. Can you ping PC2 from PC3 and vice versa?

Comment: oh sorry! Changed it !

Comment: Just to check if it was subnet/firewall related I just tried to change  the IP of PC1 and PC3 to 192.168.1.117 and 192.168.1.125 and now all the pc can ping and ssh (well except PC2 cant ssh because I dont have that open). This is why I am baffled.

Comment: I actually do also have another port in the switch connected. This one is connected to a robot and is communicating with PC2 so thats why I don't ultimately want to go around and change static IPs in my configuration..

Comment: When troubleshooting, only change one thing at a time. This will help you isolate your issue. Put everything the way you think you want it. Test. Then change one factor, and test again. In this case, I might change the IP address assigned to PC1 only, pinging it from PC2 and PC3 each time it changes. Make sure you don't have any duplicate IP addresses on the network. 

I'm curious how many clients you have. A subnet mask of 255.255.0.0 allows 65534 clients. I doubt you need that many. How come you can't just use 255.255.255.0? You want everything to talk, and that mask allows 254 clients.

Comment: You can check the routing table. You wrote the IPs are static, what about the netmask on the router? PC2 can browse in internet?